# How do I renew Craft CMS license?

Tags: plugin-development, config, license

When I go to Updates in my home Dashboard, I see there are "5 updates available!" I click "Go to Updates" and a big orange ribbon pops up that reads: Your license has expired! Renew your Craft CMS license for another year of amazing updates." 
There is a red button just above the orange ribbon that says "Renew for $59.00". 
 I click that red button and am redirected to id.craftcms.com/licenses/cms/592364. A side bar appears as follows: 

**Licenses**

Craft CMS - this page has a chart to display license keys and associated domains, but the whole chart is blank

Plug ins - same as above

Claim License - this page gives me the option to Claim a Craft License using a Key, Claim a plug in license or Claim licenses by your email address. Every single field is blank. I have no idea where to find the information to fill this in.

**Account**

Developer Support - no info

Billing - no info

Settings - my work email is here

Can someone please help me understand how to claim my license for renewal?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the original licence was purchased with a different Pixel & Tonic ID?

You could try and claim the licence by pasting your existing licence key (which you'll find in /config/license.key in your Craft installation directory) into the "claim a licence using a key" field.

If you don't have any luck there, the P&T support team are great and I'm sure they'll be able to help you out  (support@craftcms.com). There's also a good bit of information about licence keys at [craftcms.com](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/more-information-than-you-require-about-craft-license-keys)